# error CS0234. (en vscode)Tengo una solución separada en diferentes proyectos, el proyecto principal es asp.net mvc y es con autenticacion individual

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, vscode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy trabajando en una solución (en Visual Studio Code) dividida en diferentes proyectos. El proyecto principal es ASP.NET MVC, y le agregué autenticación 'Individual' al crear el proyecto. Sin embargo, al agregar los proyectos al archivo .csproj principal, obtengo el error 'CS0234: El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'AccesoDatos' no existe en el espacio de nombres 'SistemaInventario'.

Utilicé la extensión 'vscode-solution-explorer' para agregar los proyectos, y agregó estas líneas al archivo 'SistemaInventario.csproj':

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SistemaInventario.AccesoDatos\SistemaInventario.AccesoDatos.csproj"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Sin embargo, después de buscar en las profundiades del internet, encontré una forma más coherente de hacerlo:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SistemaInventario.AccesoDatos\SistemaInventario.AccesoDatos.csproj">
        <Project>{086983A9-C4FD-48F8-BF1E-962C815C4944}</Project>
        <Name>SistemaInventario.AccesoDatos</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Agregué esto, pero el error aún persiste. No puedo utilizar los proyectos y sus clases debido al error mencionado. También tengo una duda existencial: ¿La etiqueta "UserSecretsId" juega algún papel al ejecutar el comando 'dotnet run' con respecto a las rutas de los proyectos?

(Esto es solo un ejemplo de 3 proyectos).

Agradezco sus respuestas.